# Linker script: mixing memory regions and location assignments

Tags: embedded, linker-scripts

I have been looking at some linker scripts for embedded ARM processors. In one of them, there's something like this (minimal example):

```
MEMORY {
  REGION : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS {
  .text : {
    /* ... */
    . = 0x20;
    /* ... */
  } > MEMORY
}
```

This linker script states that the section `.text` should go in the memory region `REGION`, which starts at `0x1000`. However, within the section contents, the location is explicitly set to `0x20`.

**Is this location assignment relative to the start of the region that the section is in? Or absolute?** In general, how do regions and location assignments work together?

Comment: What did it say in the linker manual?

Comment: I couldn't find any material that talked about the SECTIONS region in relation to the location assignment; otherwise I wouldn't have asked on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a test. I created an assembly file with the following contents:

```
.text
.word 0x1234
```

Then I wrote a basic linker script as detailed in the question:

```
MEMORY {
    REGION : ORIGIN = 0x100, LENGTH = 0x100
}
SECTIONS {
    .text : {
        . = 0x20;
        *(.text);
    } > REGION
}
```

I compiled the assembly file to an object file with GCC, then linked the object file into an "executable" with ld. Running `objdump -s` on the result, I found that 0x1234 was at address 0x120. This means that **the location assignment is relative to the start of the memory region**.